# Can I use this old ChannelMaster antenna wallplate with Digital Antenna?

Tags: tv-antenna

I just moved into this house and have 3 of these old ChannelMaster Antenna wallplate connectors. Pretty sure this is hooked up to the antenna in my attic. It is old and I am wondering if there is an easy way to use a digital antenna with it? I found these adaptors that allow you too hook up a coaxial cable. I currently use the Mohu Leaf as my TV antenna at the moment and I stick it to the wall.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot of miss information out there concerning TV antennas and it mostly caused by marketing hype. Rabbit ears tv antennas made 50 years ago will pick up  broadcast from a  TV tower broadcasting a digital signal today if it is close enough. There are differences in quality and types, ( directional vs omni - directional- UHF, VHF etc. ). I currently have a set of rabbit ears with one of the "ears" broke off and piece of tinfoil ( it use to be my tinfoil hat ) attached and i get all the digital signals HD and non HD in my area.

It is all about placement, direction and distance.

some reading for those interested.

[NO such thing as an HDTV antenna](http://www.dennysantennaservice.com/1373792.html)

[10 things you need to know about Digital TV Antennas](http://www.antennasdirect.com/blog/10-digital-tv-antennas/)

[All About Over-The-Air Antennas](https://www.lifewire.com/over-the-air-antenna-3276138)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use this (or really, any conductor) as an antenna. If it does go to your attic, the reception might well be significantly better than a small antenna on the ground floor.

As a quick test before purchasing an adapter, if you have a basic coax cable you could try simply holding the center wire to the antenna terminals here. Tune your TV to a channel where you don't have perfect reception, and see if it improves while you hold it to each of the contacts.

As an alternative to purchasing the adapter, you could potentially replace the wallplate with something that provides a coax (aka F-type) terminal. To check if that's possible, unscrew the two dark-colored screws (which attach the plate to your wall) and see what kind of cable is attached. It might even be coax!

If for whatever reason this antenna is not sufficient, you could also probably replace the antenna in your attic but still use the existing wiring in the walls. We have a directional HDTV antenna in our attic and it provides significantly better reception than even an attic-based flat HDTV antenna.

Comment: Thanks. That is pretty much what i figured. Does a Coax cable provide any benifits over the other type of wiring which may be in there, or is it just easier to hook up to current televisions/

thanks again

Comment: Probably not significant differences if it's just at the point of connection. The coaxial *cabling* does have a benefit, in that it electrically shields the antenna conductor by surrounding it with a metal sleeve.

Comment: The connections that the wall plate uses are quite old, imagine the wire is old also and deteriorated.  Also every split in antenna cable weakens the signal strength.  Antenna to one TV= good strength, antenna with three outlets= weaker strength.

Answer (score 0):

So i bought the adaptor yesterday and tested it out. It works, but the attic antenna only picks up 30 stations vs my Mohu Leaf which is two levels below the attic and picks up almost 80 stations. Alot of those stations are religious and spanish stations. Still, the Mohu Leaf gives me alot more stations. I am going to remove the old wiring and antenna and replace with Coaxial and move the leaf to the attic.

Thanks

Comment: let us know, it may be that the location in the attic is blocked or otherwise not as good as where your leaf is currently.